# nextJS: createContext in a Server Component, adding library

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, next.js

I tried to add Framer Motion to but when i added it gave me error
the error was **TypeError: createContext only works in Client Components. Add the "use client" directive at the top of the file to use it. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/context-in-server-component**
so i added "use client" in the top then he said **error - SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse ()**

The code is

```
'use client';

import Image from 'next/image'
import { Teko, Syncopate , Sofia_Sans_Condensed, Anton} from 'next/font/google'
import { FaTelegramPlane} from 'react-icons/fa'
import { FaDiscord} from 'react-icons/fa'
import { BsShop} from 'react-icons/bs'
import Link from 'next/link'
import {motion as m} from "framer-motion"

export default function Home() {
  return (
   <m.main className='container'>
       <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </m.main>
)
```

so i added "use client" in the top then he said **error - SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse ()**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just have to change the function to the modern one(ES6) for example:

```
'use client';

const Home= () =>{
    return(

     <h1> your code </h1>
     )
}

export default Home;
```